# Excel - Cell references not updated unless I type in the number manually

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel workbook with only one worksheet. And cell 'A' is referencing to cell 'B', however, the value in cell 'A' is not equal to cell 'B' unless I type a number in cell 'B' manually. I have set the calculation option to 'Automatic' but it does not solve the problem. More specific details as following:

[image: screenshot for value display in the cells]

[image: screenshot for formula display in the cells]

The above links to pictures are the screenshots of the cells with the issue. In formula, the `J327` cell is equal to the `I329` cell, however, the value displayed in `J327` is not equal to the value in `I329` unless I type a number inside `I329` automatically. I am not sure if there are other problems in the worksheet, but after I typed some value inside `I329`, the worksheet works perfect because the sheet returns all the values as desired values. (because I am working in on a finance homework and the desired values are same as the values in the solution)

Below is the file of my workbook, and I made several copies of the same worksheet in this workbook, please find the last worksheet whose name with “after debt”.

[Altria-LBO-Revised.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/undznhkb2l2bz7z/Altria-LBO-Revised.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Check your screen shot,, I329 has SUM function and has source I327&I328, where I327 has H329 and I328 has source I324 & I327 and since H329 has ZERO may be I324 is also blank,,,, conclusion is formulas are not getting  data but has BLANK CElls so that Cell reference is not getting updated,, better show Bigger Screen shot !!

Comment: @RajeshS Edited! I324 is not blank cell and has value. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please upload the sheet to cloud Google drive or other will help to work with live sheet.

Comment: Not found those cell what you have shown with other 2 screen shots??

Comment: @RajeshS Sorry! Wrong one, I updated to the right one. I made several copies of the same worksheet in this workbook, please find the last worksheet whose name with “after debt”. Thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

The value in cell J327 is integer 0, the value in I329 cell is percentage and onvert to decimals is 0.1035. 
The value 0.1035 rounded to an integer is 0, this is why the value is different between cell J327 and I329, you can increase decimals in cell J327 or change the cell format in J327 to percentage.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry I think I mentioned in the comments but I forgot to mention in the description that the problematic worksheet is the fourth sheet which is named of "after-debt". The issue you said is in the first sheet. Sorry for the inconvenience! Thank you!